# Need to copy text from one file to another in batch file

Tags: batch-file, copy

Need to copy text from one file to another.
file1 as below:

```
locked/agent.jms.remote.host=<AGENTHOST>
locked/agent.jms.remote.port=<AGENTPORT>
```

file2 will be

```
locked/agent.jms.remote.host=mkdfvsh_a-2341
locked/agent.jms.remote.port=1234
```

&  need to replace when creating the second file

command i used:

```
SET newfile=file2
SEt filetoCOpy=file1

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%filetoCOpy%) do (
  SET "line=%%i"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET line=!line:<AGENTHOST>=%AGENTHOST%!
  SET line=!line:<AGENTPORT>=%AGENTPORT%!


      echo !line!>>%newfile%
)
```

Result i got

```
locked/agent.jms.remote.host=<AGENTHOST>
locked/agent.jms.remote.port=<AGENTPORT>
```

variable value not changing.

Can someone help here what's wrong?

Comment: why should it change? You replace the string `$installbase$` (which doesn't occure in your file)  with the content of the variable `%installbase%` - which is empty, because you don't define it.

Comment: I've modified my question above. %insatallbase% value is defined in file. insatallbase is another variable like agenthome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting an error with the code you posted. The `<` and `>` are treated as redirection unless they are escaped or quoted:

```
SET line=!line:^<AGENTHOST^>=%AGENTHOST%!
SET line=!line:^<AGENTPORT^>=%AGENTPORT%!
```

or

```
SET "line=!line:<AGENTHOST>=%AGENTHOST%!"
SET "line=!line:<AGENTPORT>=%AGENTPORT%!"
```

But you still have at least one problem - If you enable delayed expansion within a loop, then you must ENDLOCAL at the end of the loop, otherwise you can run out of SETLOCAL stack space.

Also, I don't see where AGENTHOST or AGENTPORT is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
SET newfile=file2.txt
SEt filetoCOpy=file1.txt
set "ReplaceString1=mkdfvsh_a-2341"
set "ReplaceString2=1234"
If exist %newfile% Del %newfile%

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%filetoCOpy%) do (
  SET "line=%%i"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET line=!line:^<AGENTHOST^>=%ReplaceString1%!
  SET line=!line:^<AGENTPORT^>=%ReplaceString2%!
      echo !line!>>%newfile%
)
EndLocal
start "" %newfile%
```